Is there an option to disable the display of date labels on the timeline cards in the timeline view?
I have a dataset with start and end dates for different stages of a project, along with an overall start and end date calculated as the minimum and maximum values from these stages. When I create a timeline view in Google Sheets, I can't find an option to hide the overall start and end date, which causes overlap with the stage-specific dates below. Is there a way to prevent this overlap or hide the overall dates from the timeline?
I tried to add + or - a day to the overall start and end dates however the dates still appeared overlapping as the dates on the cards were displayed in the format - MMM YY - MMM YY

Hi. Would you please read How do I ask a good question?, particularly the section on "Help others reproduce the problem". Would you please then edit the question to include sample data, the actual graph outcome and the desired outcome.

Would be good to add some examples of what you're refering to. E.g. what forumlas are you using
